# How to use travis ci with rest assured

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, travis-ci, rest-assured

I have a [jersey 2](https://jersey.java.net/) rest api. I use [rest assured](http://rest-assured.io/) for unit testing my api. I use [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/getting_started) for continuous integration. My project is using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

When the travis build gets triggered, it cannot run the tests because the connection is refused. This is normal because nothing is listening to port 8080.

When I run `mvn test` locally with tomcat running, the build works([travisci builds with this command](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#Default-script-Command)).

Travis will not start up the server for me, if I do not specify it in scripts steps.

How can I tell travis to start up the tomcat server for me ?

.travis.yml :

```
language: java
```